# generating session IDs

Tags: c, session, cgi

What is the best way to generate an HTTP session ID and avoid collisions as much as possible? How long should my session ID be?

Comment: **Off-topic**: Collisions aren't the only thing to be concerned with. You want to avoid predictability, and you probably want to ensure that a given session ID can only be used with the one IP that you issue it to (in a way that isn't obvious). (These are both anti-hacking measures.)

Comment: That's perfectly on topic :)
For the latter concern, would it be sufficient to lock the session ID to an IP address by having an IP address column for the session record in my session table? Also, if so, if a request is made with a session ID but from the wrong IP address, should I silently act logged out to that user or inform the user with an error condition?

Comment: @Delan: Having the association be on your server is obviously great for preventing spoofing, but requires a DB lookup to validate (if you're already doing a DB lookup for *other reasons*, great). *"...with a session ID but from the wrong IP address, should I silently act logged out to that user or inform the user with an error condition..."* I think that's up to you. I would opt for sending them to the login page with a general error message (nothing saying *why*), and of course log it server-side (But I bet you already had that planned).

Comment: Associating an IP with your session ID (at least for web apps) is **extremely annoying** and wrong. It's possible the client is on a mobile device that frequently roams between different networks, or even behind a proxy that load-balances outgoing connections between multiple lines with different public IP addresses. Don't do it.

Comment: R.., I understand where you're coming from, and there are legitimate uses of a single session spanning multiple IPs, but associating a session with one IP is a great way to stop session spoofing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a Guid. This will very hard to get a duplicate one.

Comment: Which version should I choose? Versions 3, 4 and 5 are quite different.

Comment: In C# there's only one Guid object. Don't know which version, but think it doesn't matter which one you use. Take the one with the most characters or the one that looks complex. Then you have the less change to get a double one. Please accept the answer when it helps you out.

Comment: Marco, I'm using C (as stated in the question's tags). I'm wondering if you think I should use v3/v5 (a hash of some non-random or non-random + random input) or v4 (purely random).